# Dcount with multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the below VBA code on my form load but getting an error:

```
Text9.Value = DCount("[Advisors]", "[tbl_ComplaintsCodedl]", "[Advisors] = '" & [Label44] & "' AND [Date] between #01/04/2016# AND #30/04/2016#")
```

The error is:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Any suggestions on which part is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *Label44* is a label and dates should of April 2016:

```
Text9.Value = DCount("*", "[tbl_ComplaintsCodedl]", "[Advisors] = '" & [Label44].Caption & "' And [Date] Between #2016/04/01# And #2016/04/30#")
```

And do assign meaningful names to your controls.